# Why element does not go to the center?

Tags: html, css

Why the image does not go to the center in HTML? I have entered margin to auto.

```html
<div style="margin: 20px auto" class="elem">
  <img 
     src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/online-test-concept-illustration_114360-5486.jpg"
     alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: You need to also set the `width` of the element too

Comment: `I have entered margin to auto.` yes you did, but on the `div`, and the width of the `div` is `auto`.

Answer (score 5):

You can either...

Add `text-align:center;` to your div

**OR**

Add `display:block; margin: auto;` to your image

Answer (score 1):

```css
.elem{
    border: 1px solid;
}
.elem img{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
  <img 
     src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/online-test-concept-illustration_114360-5486.jpg"
     alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use style "text-align: center" then it will go to center

```
<div style="margin: 20px auto; text-align: center;" class="elem" >
    <img
      src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/online-test-concept-illustration_114360-5486.jpg"
      alt=""
    />
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
   <div style="margin: 20px auto" class="elem">
     <img
     style="display: block; margin: auto;"
     src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/online-test-concept- 
     illustration_114360-5486.jpg"
     alt=""
     />
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to check the display property of your element. And margin auto works only with those elements which has display property as "block".
So if you still  want to use margin:auto, you have to use with Display block.
Otherwise you can use text-align:center